# Should I close my cursors in an exception clause?

Tags: oracle, database-cursor

Do I need to take care of open cursors in case of a procedure/function critical failure?
Suppose I have:

```
PROCEDURE example IS
CURSOR c_example IS 
    SELECT 1 FROM dual;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_example
       some processing that causes a failure(...)
    CLOSE c_example;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF c_example%ISOPEN
            THEN CLOSE c_example;
        END IF;
        RAISE;
END;
/
```

Wouldn't such a failure somehow take care of my open cursor on its own?
Do I need to close it manually?

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=closing-cursors-200304

Comment: Thank you. Should I delete my original question?

Comment: It is a valid question, so perhaps OldProgrammer can make his link into an answer instead?